# Is it possible to add pictures?

Tags: feature-request

Can you add pictures to a post here? I don't see a button. If we don't have this feature, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add images; every time I try I have to go look up [the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)

```
![Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can add pictures just by clicking on this icon:

[image]

Comment: That never shows up in history SE for me.

Comment: @Mustang That's strange. I suppose it might have been disabled for low rep users, but I don't remember ever not having that.

Comment: As a newer participant, my rep is lower than Mustang's. But picture icon shows for me, both History.SE & Meta. Of course, comments don't include formatting aids, maybe that's what @Mustang is confused by.